# How to create desktop icon / button to start users Windows screensaver with options set

Tags: c++, batch-file, windows-8

I need a button I can put on the users desktop/process bar in Windows 8 (any sub menu is unacceptable), that will start the users screensaver (with password protection, custom parameters etc). This can for example be a shortcut to a batch script.

Some suggestions for solutions I have found:

**Starting screensaver from /system32**: Does not work

1. Starts a specific screensaver you choose, not the users screensaver.
2. Does not take parameters (ie wrong text/pic and no password protection).

**WIN + L**: Does not work.

1. It is not a button on the users Desktop, and SendKeys does not seem to be able to do the WIN key, so a batch script for this is not possible.
2. It goes to log in screen, not screensaver.

**rundll32.exe user32.dll, LockWorkStation**: Does not work.

1. It corrupts the stack - https://blogs.msdn.microsoft.com/oldnewthing/20040115-00/?p=41043/

**C++ program**: So far this is what I have that might work.

```
#include <windows.h>

int WINAPI WinMain(HINSTANCE hInstance, HINSTANCE hPrevInstance, LPTSTR lpCmdLine, int cmdShow)
{
  HWND DeskWin = GetDesktopWindow();
  Sleep(750);
  PostMessage(DeskWin, WM_SYSCOMMAND, SC_SCREENSAVE, NULL);
  return 0;
}
```

I have never worked with Windows system messages before, so any comments / thoughts on if this will always work is appreciated.

Or if someone just have a way they think is better.

--
Reasons for the need: IT-scared users. They will laugh at you if you suggest remembering a hotkey combination, or going through multiple menus (like Start -> userName -> Lock), the latter is also a time problem as they might have to leave computer fast (hence the need for password protection).

EDIT** C++ Code has been modified to reflect feedback. Sendmessage changed to Postmessage, don't want a blocking call in a codesnip like this (but don't see why it should be thrown at DefWindowProc when the window is known). Symbolic names found (http://wiki.winehq.org/List_Of_Windows_Messages , can't post more links, MSDN has the second parameters under WM_SYSCOMMAND), WinMain is a Visual Studio thing to avoid the console pop up, which some people find alarming.

Comment: The difference between GUI and commandline commands (key sequences you need to remember) is big. Why would I install a program that does the same as the standard screensaver settings?

Comment: Users can't change the timeouts if you deny them that right.(see group policies). Your comments has nothing to do with my question and your suggestions are completely useless / wrong.

Comment: Sending a system message to the desktop window work (or should work), but just (1) process it via `DefWindowProc`, (2) use the symbolic name, not magic numbers, and (3) remember to add a little delay with consumption of any user input, lest mouse movements stop the screensaver as soon as it's started.

Comment: No prob. Deleting them. Excuse me for trying to help. I promise it won't happen again.

Comment: Thank you Alf. I can't find any details on why I want DefWindowProc over SendMessage, is it possible to explain in short or provide a link? As for symbolic names, need to find them somewhere, and yeah it needs a delay.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There is no built-in batch command for running the user's screensaver (without using a 3rd party solution to facilitate it). The code you have come up with is the correct solution for starting the user's screen saver.  However, don't use magic number literals like you have shown. There are defines available for those values, use them:

```
#include <windows.h>

int main(void)
{
    SendMessage(GetDesktopWindow(), WM_SYSCOMMAND, SC_SCREENSAVE, 0);
    return 0;
}
```

Compile your code into an `.exe` file, install it on the user's PC somewhere, and create a shortcut to it on the user's Desktop.

Comment: Is NULL not a better choice for LParam than 0? Since it represent cursor position if read. (thought I posted this once already but don't see it).

Comment: The `lParam` parameter is not a pointer, it is an integer (`LPARAM` is an alias for `LONG_PTR`, which is an alias for `long` in 32bit and `__int64` in 64bit). `NULL` is just an alias for 0. The `lParam` has no meaning in the `SC_SCREENSAVE` notification. Read the [`WM_SYSCOMMAND` documentation](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms646360.aspx). Even if coordinates were specified, they are not passed as a pointer, the `lParam` value would have to be created using the [`MAKELPARAM()`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms632661.aspx) macro instead.

Comment: "lParam

    The low-order word specifies the horizontal position of the cursor, in screen coordinates, if a window menu command is chosen with the mouse. Otherwise, this parameter is not used. "

Comment: I did read that link, which is why I know its a location if its used. But I forgot c++ doesn't have a real NULL value. Still it shows the reader of the code the value is not meant to be used rather than have to go read the documentation to see why you send 0. But it is also true the NULL is sometimes recommended to not use in c++.